# Trying to push vector<int> to map to calculate mode

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I am trying to insert a vector value (v[i]) into a map and have the 2nd variable be the counter for number of times that first variable has been entered.

Thinking through the pseudo code I'm pretty sure I'll need a for loop to run through the vector and insert the value into the map, could I create an int counter = 1; and insert that as the second value and if it's already there increment it? I've tried a few things but haven't been able to work it out, any input is help!

My code:

```
std::pair<std::map<int, int>::iterator, bool> temp; 
temp = mInt.insert(std::pair<int, int>(v[i], counter)); 
if (temp.second == false) { counter++; } 
if (counter >= mode) { mode = counter; }
```

Comment: Hi, @Cellery72.  Can you show your code or pseudocode?  You're asking a yes/no question but I'm sure you're looking for more than yes/no.

Comment: Showing exactly what you've tried and your expected inputs and outputs will help others to help you.

Comment: My apologies, this is the code I have so far

 std::pair<std::map<int, int>::iterator, bool> temp;
  temp = mInt.insert(std::pair<int, int>(v[i], counter));
  if (temp.second == false) {
   counter++;
  }


  if (counter >= mode)
  {
   
   mode = counter;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that you want to iterate over a vector.  Each element in the vector is to become a key (or index) for a std::map structure.  The corresponding value will be a counter.

The end result is that the std::map structure will contain a count for how many times each item in the vector is repeated.

This is how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main (){

  // Set up a vector of items.  Our items are ints, but any object that
  // can be inserted as a map key is fine.
  std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 4, 8, 16, 8 };

  // Set up a std::map where the "key" (or index) is the same type as
  // the vector's elements.  The "value" will be our counter.
  std::map<int,size_t> m;

  // Iterate over the vector.  Use each element as a map key. Increment
  // the value indexed by the key.  This is our counter.
  for( auto e : v ) {
    m[e]++;
  }


  // Now iterate over the map, printing out the key, and its
  // corresponding count.
  for ( auto e : m ) {
    std::cout << e.first << " => " << e.second << "\n";
  }


  return 0;
}
```

The line, "`m[e]++;`" may seem a little confusing, but consider how `operator[]` works for map containers:  If an element doesn't exist by a given index, it is created using the value's default constructor.  A reference to the value is then returned, which we then increment using `operator++`.  So the first time a "16" is seen, its map element will be created, and then its counter incremented from 0 (default) to 1.  The second time 16 is seen, it will just have its value incremented, this time from 1 to 2.

This is a C++ adaptation of a very common Perl idiom:

```
my @v = ( 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 4, 8, 16, 8 );
my %m;
$m{$_}++ for @v;
print "$_ => $m{$_}\n" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %m;
```

The C++ implementation could use `std::unordered_map`.  This would be a closer approximation of the Perl version.  `unordered_map` reduces the counting algorithm from O(n log n) to O(n) amortized time complexity. But depending on your needs, the output might then need to be sorted, which has a cost as well.  However, since there are expected to be duplicate elements in the vector, that means the map or unordered_map size will be smaller (in number of elements) than the vector.  So even if sorted output is needed, unordered_map could be a net win.